# Import media python 3

Tags: python-3.x, import, media

I installed the media module for python 3; however, my code simply won't print. I am trying to simply this certain instances for the class I defined.

```
from pygraphics import media

class Movie():

  def __init__(self, movie_title, movie_story, movie_img, movie_trailer):
     self.title=movie_title
     self.story_line=movie_story
     self.imgurl=movie_img
     self.trailer_youtube=movie_trailer



toy_story=media.Movie("Toy Story", "A story of a boy and his toys that come to life", "url", "url1")

print(toy_story.movie_story)
```

Comment: What is the error msg?

Comment: There actually isn't an error message. It simply isn't printing.

Comment: What happens if you do print("test")? Does it output test?

Comment: When I test it, it also doesn't print

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to import a module you are trying to import the file you created called "media". You can name the media file "motorcycle" and get the same thing. The issue is that word media is causing an issue. Change media to something else like mymedia, save it and import the name of that file.

C:/Movie_Project/mymedia.py

class Movie():
    def **init** (self, movie_title, movie_storyline, poster_image,
                 trailer_youtube):
        self.title = movie_title
        self.storyline = movie_storyline
        self.poster_image_url = poster_image
        self.trailer_youtube_url = trailer_youtube

C:/Movie_Project/entertainment_center.py

import mymedia

toy_story = mymedia.Movie("Toy Story",
                        "A story of a boy and his toys that come to life",
                        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/13/Toy_Story.jpg",
                        "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwyZH85NQC4")
print(toy_story.storyline)